# flask-restful unable to add headers into response

Tags: flask, http-headers, flask-restful

I have a flask-restful Resource like so

```
class UserLogin(Resource):
    @classmethod
    def post(cls):
        return {"msg": "test"}, 200, {"Foo": "bar"}
```

It should be the case that in the headers of my response, 'Foo' is set to 'bar', but I am unable to see it.

I do see the json body {'msg':'test'} in response, however.

Comment: problem not reproducible on my end, but you are not showing a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your code.

Comment: @ilias-sp Sorry about that, the project was too big for me to figure out a starting point of a MRE. Found the issue though - Flask-CORS follows the CORS spec which requires the server to give explicit permissions for the client to read headers in CORS responses. 
In order for me to send headers other than what is defaulted, I must explicitly configure to include those keys.

Comment: great, case closed!